# in aspx page social sharing by using addthis where it is not sharing image, title, desciption data so i had added meta tag not working

Tags: javascript, facebook-social-plugins, add-this-event

I used addthis plugin where it is not sharing data in facebook, twitter, linkedin,whatsaap so i had added meta tags where meta tags sharing working with static content but aspx page has dymanic post where data by API.

I need dymanic meta tag where data from api append in the meta tags.

During degbugging in facebook debugger it is not showing dynamic data.

**These are the meta tags**

```
 <meta name="twitter:title" content="Impact Of Labor Reforms On Ease Of Doing Business">
 <meta name="twitter:description" content="Already lots have been discussed about the migrant laborer’s and their difficulties, so delving deep into the solutions which the central government has come out with through the amendments in the labor laws as committed at the beginning of 2020.">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://advantagehrm.com/Uploads/UploadImage/Img2b251f472-7a88-4110-8acd-4677aa461696.jpg" />   
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://advantagehrm.com/Uploads/UploadImage/Img2b251f472-7a88-4110-8acd-4677aa461696.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">  
    <meta property="og:title" content="Impact Of Labor Reforms On Ease Of Doing Business">   
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://advantagehrm.com/PostMaster/DetailNews.aspx?id=69">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://advantagehrm.com/Uploads/UploadImage/Img2b251f472-7a88-4110-8acd-4677aa461696.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://advantagehrm.com/Uploads/UploadImage/Img2b251f472-7a88-4110-8acd-4677aa461696.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Already lots have been discussed about the migrant laborer’s and their difficulties, so delving deep into the solutions which the central government has come out with through the amendments in the labor laws as committed at the beginning of 2020.">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="899581643899672">
```

**This is code to append data in meta tags**

```
 $(document).prop('title',getData[j].PostTitle);            
                             $('#divMeta').attr('data-title', getData[j].PostTitle);                                        
                            $('#divMeta').attr('data-description', getData[j].Description.substring(1,20));
                            $('#divMeta').attr('data-media','https://advantagehrm.com' + getData[j].PostImg.replace("~", ""));
                           
                           
                           $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr('content',getData[j].PostTitle);   
                           $("meta[name='twitter\\:title']").attr('content',getData[j].PostTitle);
                           
                           
                           $("meta[name='twitter\\:image\\:src']").attr('content', 'https://advantagehrm.com' + getData[j].PostImg.replace("~", ""));
                           $("meta[name='twitter\\:image']").attr('content', 'https://advantagehrm.com' + getData[j].PostImg.replace("~", ""));
                           $("meta[property='og\\:image\\:secure_url']").attr('content','https://advantagehrm.com' + getData[j].PostImg.replace("~", ""));
```

Comment: Looks like you are adding the metatags with javascript. That is not good, you need to add them directly in the html before it loads for Facebook to pick it up, you can do it from the server with the language you are using (ASP, PHP) or directly in the HTML

Comment: in this page the post are loading by id where data came from api thats why i need to update or append data by javascript what can i do

Comment: I understand but it won't work that way

Comment: what can i do sir plz tell me